# Swift 4. How can I make method return bool from Firebase completion handler

Tags: ios, swift

```
override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {

    if identifier == "ChosenCell" {

        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: sender as! UITableViewCell) {
            reference.child("List").child(storyArray[indexPath.row].name).observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded) { snapshot in
                let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String,String>

                if snapshotValue["Creator"]! != self.currentUser!.email! {
                    //return false
                    //continue
                } else {
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "Enter password:", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { alertAction in
                        let textField = alert.textFields![0] as UITextField
                        if textField.text! != snapshotValue["Password"]! {
                            //return false
                        }
                    }
                    alert.addTextField { textField in
                        textField.placeholder = "password"
                    }
                    alert.addAction(action)
                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

When user choose cell if user is currentUser or if there is no password "ChosenCell" segue should perform.
Else alert: "Please enter password". And if the password is right "ChosenCell" segue should perform.
How can I do this?

Comment: I mean: "If user is the creator of this cell". Not "currentUser"

Answer (score 0):

In this case func shouldPerformSegue always returns true, because observeSingleEvent performs in background thread and shouldPerformSegue doesn't wait for completion of observeSingleEvent.
You should implement logic in this way:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let name = storyArray[indexPath.row].name
    reference.child("List").child(name).observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded) { snapshot in

        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [String : String]
        if snapshotValue["Creator"]! == self.currentUser!.email! { // user is the creator of this cell, so perform segue
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "ChosenCell", sender: nil)
        } else { // user is not the creator of this cell
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "Enter password:", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { alertAction in
                let textField = alert.textFields!.first
                if textField.text! != snapshotValue["Password"]! { // wrong password
                    // show error message
                } else { // right password
                    performSegue(withIdentifier: "ChosenCell", sender: nil)
                }
            }
            alert.addTextField { textField in
                textField.placeholder = "password"
            }
            alert.addAction(action)
            present(alert, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```